# SQL Server Recursion select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have two tables:

```
entreprises(id, name)
entreprises_struct(id,entreprise_id, entreprise_child_id)
```

let's say i have these data:

```
entreprises:
(1,canada)
(2,ontario)
(3,quebec)
(4,ottawa)
(5,toronto)
(6,montreal)
(7,laval)

entreprises_struct
(1,1,1)
(1,1,2)
(1,1,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,2,5)
(1,3,6)
(1,3,7)
```

I want a query that will sort the data in this way :

```
montreal  (child level 3)
laval  (child level 3)
quebec (child level 2 and parent of those childs from level 3)
ottawa (child level 3)
toronto (child level 3)
ontario (child level 2 and parent of those childs from level 3)
canada (chil level 1 and parent of thoses childs from level 2)
```

If I had that from level 7 , the select must start listing thoses values till level one.

I cannot use CTE because the numbers on recursions is too much limited.

Comment: `"MAXRECURSION number

    Specifies the maximum number of recursions allowed for this query. number is a non-negative integer between 0 and 32767. When 0 is specified, no limit is applied. If this option is not specified, the default limit for the server is 100. "`

Hence `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` would allow CTE's with infinite recursion.

Comment: Is there a reason why montreal/laval MUST come before ottawa/toronto? If you drew a graph/tree with them, quebec/ontario would be on the same level, so is the max(id) the tiebreaker?

Comment: @Richard : no there is no reason , otawwa/toronto can come before montreal/laval. if i drew a graph/tree quebec/ontario would be on the same level because the have the same parent_id (entreprise_id in entreprise_struct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `option(maxrecursion 0)` to get around the CTE recursion limit.  As for the sorting part of the query, see the below

Sample data

```
create table entreprises(id int, name varchar(max));
create table entreprises_struct(id int, entreprise_id int, entreprise_child_id int);
insert entreprises values
(1,'canada'),
(2,'ontario'),
(3,'quebec'),
(4,'ottawa'),
(5,'toronto'),
(6,'montreal'),
(7,'laval');
insert entreprises_struct values
(1,1,1),
(1,1,2),
(1,1,3),
(1,2,4),
(1,2,5),
(1,3,6),
(1,3,7);
```

The query

```
;with cte as (
select entreprise_id, level=0,
    path=convert(varchar(max),entreprise_id) + '/'
from entreprises_struct
where entreprise_id =entreprise_child_id -- root
union all
select s.entreprise_child_id, cte.level+1,
    path=cte.path + convert(varchar(max),s.entreprise_child_id) + '/'
from entreprises_struct s
inner join cte on s.entreprise_id = cte.entreprise_id
where s.entreprise_child_id != cte.entreprise_id
)
select e.name
from cte
inner join entreprises e on e.id = cte.entreprise_id
order by path desc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```